# How to do people search based on keywords using linkedin api in R?

Tags: r, linkedin-api, httr

I am trying to extract profile search data based on keywords. It is showing access is denied.

1) How to get people search data using linkedin api in R ? (But I am getting data on apigee rest console) .

2) What is the best way store XML data as Data Frame in R? When there is a differ in rows between root node?

Below is my code.

```
library(httr)
library(XML)

oauth_endpoints("linkedin")

myapp <- oauth_app("Profile Search", key  = "785mvlu4741k9o", secret="DMRmtjDfFo4ncLzg")

TokenLinkedIn <- R6::R6Class("TokenLinkedIn", inherit = Token2.0, list(
  sign = function(method, url) {
    url <- parse_url(url)
    url$query$oauth2_access_token <- self$credentials$access_token
    list(url = build_url(url), config = config())
  },
  can_refresh = function() {
    TRUE
  },
  refresh = function() {
    self$credentials <- init_oauth2.0(self$endpoint, self$app,
                                      scope = self$params$scope, type = self$params$type,
                                      use_oob = self$params$use_oob)
  }
))

token <- TokenLinkedIn$new(
  endpoint = oauth_endpoints("linkedin"),
  app = myapp,
  params = list(use_oob = FALSE, scope = NULL, type = NULL)
)

homeTL<- GET("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search:(people:(first-name,last-name,headline,industry,email-address))?keywords=client%20engagement"
, config(token = token))

homeTL
# I am getting below error message as Access to people search denied.
#<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
#<error>
  #<status>403</status>
  #<timestamp>1425299488038</timestamp>
  #<request-id>JXQYYV5V0Z</request-id>
  #<error-code>0</error-code>
  #<message>Access to people search denied.</message>
# </error>


doc <- xmlTreeParse(homeTL,useInternal=TRUE)
rootNode <- xmlRoot(doc)
Id<-xpathSApply(rootNode,"//id", xmlValue)
firstname<-xpathSApply(rootNode,"//first-name", xmlValue)
lastname<-xpathSApply(rootNode,"//last-name", xmlValue)
industry<-xpathSApply(rootNode,"//industry", xmlValue)

Link=data.frame("Id"=Id,"FirstName"=firstname,"LastName"=lastname)

## While including industry rows showing error 
#Error in data.frame(Id = Id, FirstName = firstname, LastName = lastname,  : 
  #                    arguments imply differing number of rows: 842, 786
```

Answer (score 1):

[LinkedIn has recently made changes to their Developer Program](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes), removing the ability to people search.

Comment: Note, however, that this doesn't kick in until May 12th, 2015.

Comment: @JustinKominar I couldn't undertand. Is it possible to do?

Comment: @KaramChand Yes - it's possible, for now.  But as the original comment mentions, that will not be the case after May 12th.  I don't have specific R experience, however, to help with your original question.  I just wanted to let you know that what you're trying to do will not be possible too much longer.

Comment: the people search limit is now in place. However, the limit is for those performing call more than 250 times a day. If you do have more than 250 access a day, you have to get special permission. See here (https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/blog/vetted-api-access)